# can we alter activity tables to add extra column?

Tags: activiti

My requirement is like we have created activity  tables when the initial server start has been done and now i want add a extra column to ACT_HI_TASK table.

Is it possible to perform add column to existing table?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the schema for the Activiti system tables is managed by the Ibatis ORM. In order to modify the schema you need to update the Ibatis definition files (schema and CRID operation sql) as well as the Entity classes that manage these tables.
Keep in mind, upgrades will overwrite any changes you make so this becomes a maintenance issue. But, certainly possible.

Comment: Thanks alot for providing answer and i have one more thing to ask can i add or retrieve entry from  ACT_HI_TASK table that which is not a part of activiti workflow process

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. You can always use management service to make custom sql queries of any of the Activiti system tables. Perhaps this is all you need:

https://www.activiti.org/javadocs/6.latest/org/activiti/engine/managementservice